# Show and hide tooltips with CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, tooltip, toggle, visibility

I use CSS to show and hide tooltips when I hover over them. Now I need this to work for mobile devices with a click function. I got the first tooltip running through toggling a class via Javascript. How can I apply that function for all tooltips now? I have around 30 to 40. Any idea how I can achieve my goal?

```js
document.getElementById("website-tooltip-container").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("test");
  element.classList.toggle("website-tooltiptext-visible");
});
```

```css
/* Tooltip Container */

.website-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #666;
}


/* Tooltip text */

.website-tooltip .website-tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  max-width: 350px;
  font-family: open sans;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #666;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 11px 15px 11px 15px !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Position the tooltip text */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.website-tooltip:hover .website-tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* Hide when hovering over tooltip div */

div.website-tooltiptext:hover {
  display: none;
}


/* Toggle this class to show Tooltip on click via Javascript */

.website-tooltiptext-visible {
  visibility: visible !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="website-tooltip-container" class="website-tooltip"><span class="dottedunderline">Tooltip 1</span>
  <div id="test" class="website-tooltiptext">Blabalabalbalablablabla.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="website-tooltip-container" class="website-tooltip"><span class="dottedunderline">Tooltip 2</span>
  <div id="test" class="website-tooltiptext">Blabalabalbalablablabla.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="website-tooltip-container" class="website-tooltip"><span class="dottedunderline">Tooltip 3</span>
  <div id="test" class="website-tooltiptext">Blabalabalbalablablabla.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="website-tooltip-container" class="website-tooltip"><span class="dottedunderline">Tooltip 4</span>
  <div id="test" class="website-tooltiptext">Blabalabalbalablablabla.
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use an extra class.
add this to your css:

```
 .website-tooltiptext-visible {
            visibility: visible !important;
        }
```

and replace this class inside your js code:

```
element.classList.toggle("website-tooltiptext-visible");
```

PS: NEVER use same id for multiple HTML elements. like ever!

EDIT: use below javascript code to select by class

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("website-tooltiptext")).forEach(
    (element) => {
        element.addEventListener("click", () => {
            element.classList.toggle("website-tooltiptext-visible");
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Clicking it works now. But there are 2 issues left. 1.) When the tooltip is clicked and opened, it is possible to hover the tooltip container behind it. How can I avoid that. 2.) How can I get the other tooltips running via click? Does every tooltip need an own Javascript with an own id? Because I have a lot of tooltips, like 30 or 40. Is there a simpler solution? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Problem 1.) I solved with entering the code `display: block !important;` to `.website-tooltiptext-visible` (see snippet). But still I don´t know how to solve problem 2.) in an easy way without having to copy the Javascript 40 times and always entering an unique id... :/

Comment: I updated the answer, use getElementsByClassName to get all elements with specific CSS class.
I highly recommend you to switch to dynamic web development. They build the whole page with javascript. It is fast, component base, reusable  and so on. I can show you some basis if you are interested.

Comment: Sorry but your code brings no solution. If I enter it in the snippet an error message occurs and the tooltips aren´t clickable. Still thanks that you tried.

Comment: Sorry. my bad! I fixed it.

Comment: Mmmmh... did u test it? Because this code has no effect. Error message is gone but clicking the tooltips does nothing. I think Javascript is the devil... CSS makes sense but Javascript is just Chinese for me.

Comment: yes. I tested it. Actually I use desktop Chrome in mobile mode, not a real mobile. in this mode, first click acts like hover, so there is no need for eventListener at all. but I logged every elements inside forEach to make sure it works.

Comment: Mmh... that´s weird. How can it work on your site but not on my? I tested it here in the code snippet editor. Result is that nothing happens. Tested it then also on my site. Result is the same... also nothing happens. Tested it also in "'Touch Mode" in Firefox and also with the "normal" mouse click. Also no results... Still thanks.